# Dealing with .csv files in java (newbie level)

Tags: java

I'm trying to get certain data from .csv file and print it to output. `String` type brings no problems, but dealing with `int` makes makes me wonder. I tried to create an array from the file and extract needed elements from it, but the code won't compile at all.

```
package readcvs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadCVS {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ReadCVS obj = new ReadCVS();
        obj.run();
    }

  public void run() {

        String csvFile = "/Users/hobbit/Desktop/E0.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String csvSplitBy = ",";
         try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // comma is used as a separator
                String[] tie = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                System.out.println(tie[2] + " vs " + tie[3]);
                String[] ref = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                System.out.println ("Referee: " + ref[10]);

                int digit = Integer.valueOf(line);
                //convert String to integer

                int[] shotsarr = new int[digit];
                System.out.println("Home team shots: " + shotsarr[11]);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to reinvent? you can use existing solutions like supercsv

Comment: If the code doesn't compile, you must have a compilation error message. What is it?

Comment: you will run into problems with the following line `Integer.valueOf(line);` i think you want to parse the String in your array tie instead at some certain index. Currently you are trying to parse every line you read from the CSV into an Integer which will throw a NumberFormatException

Comment: You're splitting the line twice which is pointless. Once you have split the line then work with the resulting array and ignore the line. For starters, to better understand the content of the array I would suggest removing the code that tries to convert to integer and instead create a for loop and print each element in the array. Once you have code that compiles and prints the content of the array for each line when run then you can move on and convert strings to int.

Comment: @techtrainer I just wanted to keep it simple. However, thanks for the hint. I'll try using supercsv

Comment: @Aaron `run:
HomeTeam vs AwayTeam
Referee: Referee
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR,Referee,HS,AS,HST,AST,HF,AF,HC,AC,HY,AY,HR,AR
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
 at readcvs.ReadCVS.run(ReadCVS.java:33)
 at readcvs.ReadCVS.main(ReadCVS.java:12)
C:\Users\hobbit\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1`

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. I'll try to follow your advice

Comment: That's a runtime error, not a compile-time error ;) It's the `Integer.valueOf(line)` previously mentionned

Comment: So, I think I should use another method if I won't find the solution in the mentioned before supercsv. Thanks for your help :)